# How to implement pushnotification using C2DM in android?

Tags: android, android-c2dm

I would like to make app in android in which i wand to send some message to server and also want to get notification from server if there is any updates via C2DM in android.

How to send message to the third party server. (Third-party server like php)and inputs are necessary to send message to the third-party server. and how to send response Third-party server to C2DM and get notification from C2DM to Android device?

Answer (score 1):

Well that's like asking "How do I write an Android application?" and expect to get a full answer.

I suggest you start with reading this:
http://code.google.com/intl/sv-SE/android/c2dm/index.html

Then download the Chrome To Phone source code see how they implement the C2DM solution. It is fairly complicated but if you know how to make http POSTs from your Android application and your server you will succeed.

Comment: That's a lovely URL and it works fine for me, but I'd probably not use the international version. :-)  http://code.google.com/android/c2dm/